# How to add details to tooltip other than title

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, popover

We normally use tooltip like this

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip On Right</button>
```

Here we are adding the details in the title part

But I am having lots of details that need to add in the title elements like Profile picture, Designation, First name, Last Name, etc...

So, I am not able to pass it in the title

Is there any other option to fix this?

Also currently, this tooltip is coming when I am hovering it... I need it to show once I click it

Comment: I think it's popovers you're looking for, not tooltips https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Comment: view tooltip example and also download source code with this url:  https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/07/tooltip-styles-inspiration/

Comment: if you want to have full control you could add a `div` containing all the information you need. Position it absolutely and show it on `focus`. Or use a little javascript to toggle show/hide of that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comments suggest, you should use Popovers instead of tooltip.

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  })
</script>
<h1>Popover Example</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Popove`enter code here`r content. example content for popover">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Also you can HTML option to add more flexible content.

Reference: [Bootstrap Popovers Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/popovers/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an absolute `div` and show/hide it when you click on the button using a little bit of javascript. And position it how you want.

This is a 'classic' way of doing this. Without any plugins or libraries.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('tooltip-btn');

button.onclick = function() {
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip-content');
  tooltip.style.display === 'none' ?
  tooltip.style.display = 'inline-block ' : tooltip.style.display = 'none'
  }
```

```css
div#tooltip-content {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  left:80px;
  top:25px;
 
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-wrapper">
  <button id="tooltip-btn" class="btn btn-success">Tooltip On Right</button>
  <div id="tooltip-content" style="display:none">
    <h2>SOme title</h2>
    <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
    <a href="#"> Link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

User Popovers instead of Tooltip . find document [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  Also, there's already a comment saying the exact same thing.